# Need help to Print the names of departments that have one or more majors who are under 18 years old

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Looking for guidance on the following question:
Print the name of departments that have one or more majors who are under 18 years old.

```
My table looks like this:
Student(sid,sname,sex,age,year,qpa)
Dept(dname,numphds)
Prof (pname,dname)
Course (cno,cname,dname)
Major(dname,sid)
Section(dname,cno,sectno,pname)
Enroll(sid,grade,dname,cno,sectno)
```

I ended up getting results using the following:

```
SELECT dept.dname
FROM dept
INNER JOIN major on major.dname = dept.dname
INNER JOIN student on major.sid = student.sid and student.age<18
group by dept.dname
having count(*)>0
limit 5;
```

Comment: `I wrote the following code, but think I am missing something`.  Why do you think that?  What results are you getting, and what's wrong?  Although now that I've said it, your `having` clause is almost certainly wrong.

Comment: I changed the having clause to where clause, but it looks like the error is within the join clause and group by clause. Wouldn't I have to tie the major.dname to the dept.dname in order to print the names of the depts that have one or more majors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the `FROM` clause related to `DEPT` table and a second `JOIN` to the `STUDENT` table (linked by `SID`). Also, you need to limit the `JOIN` on student that are under 18. And then, finally, you need `dname` that have at least 1 student that match the age criteria...

```
SELECT DISTINCT dept.dname
FROM dept
inner join major on major.dname = dept.dname
inner join student on major.sid = student.sid and student.age < 18
group by dept.dname
having count(*)>0;
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! I was able to get results using your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand it, but here's an attempt without seeing any real data:

Think about the following:

- `INNER JOIN` requires a relationship be present (a match on both sides), which fulfills the majors requirement.
- Filter by age to restrict those with ages equal to above 18.
- Distill it down to the *distinct* departments we care about (e.g. "DEPT A" with age=17, "DEPT A" with age=16-- we only need one "DEPT A").

> `SELECT DISTINCT d.dname           -- "print the name of departments"`
> `FROM            Dept d            --`
>  `INNER JOIN    Major m           -- "that have one or more majors"`
>   `INNER JOIN  Student s         --`
>   `ON          s.sid = m.sid     --`
>  `ON            m.dname = d.dname --`
> `WHERE           s.Age < 18        -- "who are under 18 years old"`

Comment: You passed. Now collect your diploma.